# No --wait or --no-async when creating Google Cloud container node pool?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using Google Cloud / Google Container Engine, and I have infrastructure scripts where I create a cluster and node pools and then perform operations on the node pools once they're setup.

In my scripts, I need to make sure that the node pools are setup and the cluster is in a ready state before proceeding.

It appears that the `gcloud container node-pools create` command has no `--wait` or `--no-async` option, unlike the very similar `gcloud container node-pools delete`.  Is there such an option for `create`?  Else, is there a recommended way to "wait" until the node pool is ready?

I believe in my bash scripts, after creating a node pool, I can do a while loop, periodically checking the value of e.g. `gcloud container clusters describe myclustername --zone myzone | tail -n 2 | grep "status" | awk '{print $2}'` until I get "`RUNNING`" back, but perhaps there is a more elegant approach?

(It would be nice to have parity in options for creating and deleting node pools!)

Comment: I cannot think on a much different workaround. Could you provide some additional details on your use case? What kind of operations do you need to run on the node pools after they get ready?

Comment: @davewy, please feel free to submit a feature request on [google-cloud-sdk issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) for adding this flags to `gcloud container node-pools create` command.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing the [`gcloud container node-pools create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/node-pools/create) command is sync by default but doesn't have an `--async` or `--no-wait` option. This isn't so bad from a shell scripting perspective as it's easy enough to background a command, and would solve your particular issue.

An alternative to deal with the original behavior would have been to use `--log-http` to grab the operation ID and feed it to `gcloud container operations wait` (which is a bit messy and requires scraping the output). This suggests another feature which would be nice to have, which is for async commands to echo the operation ID.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this script that will wait for any container operations that are not done yet.

wait_container_operations.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# This scripts runs gcloud container `operations describe` and `wait` for all found operations with `list --filter=STATUS!=DONE`
# API outlined here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/operations/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

source_dir="$(dirname "$0")";
current_dir="$(pwd)";
echo "Listing, describing and awaiting NOT-DONE container-operations";

function sourceClusterZone(){
    cd $source_dir;
    source ./cluster_zone.sh;
    cd $current_dir;
}

queryNotDone(){ gcloud container operations list --filter=STATUS!=DONE --sort-by='~START_TIME'; }

listNotDone(){ queryNotDone | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $1;}}'; }

sleep 2;
LISTNOTDONE=(`listNotDone`);
echo "\""${LISTNOTDONE[@]}"\"";
if (( ${#LISTNOTDONE[@]} )); then
sourceClusterZone;
for notDone in ${LISTNOTDONE[@]}
do
    echo "Waiting for $notDone";
    gcloud container operations describe $notDone --zone="${ZONE}";
    gcloud container operations wait $notDone --zone="${ZONE}";
    echo "Done with $notDone";
done
else
    echo 'Not Waiting';
fi
```

cluster_zone.sh (in same dir)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

kubeClusterOptions(){ kubectl config current-context | awk -F '_' 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; {print $4} {print $3}'; }

declare -a OPTIONS;
IFS=' ' read -a OPTIONS <<< `kubeClusterOptions`; IFS=$'\n\t';

while getopts c:z: option 
    do 
        case "${option}" 
        in 
        c) CLUSTER=${OPTARG:-${OPTIONS[0]}};; 
        z) ZONE=${OPTARG:-${OPTIONS[1]}};; 
    esac 
done
export CLUSTER=${CLUSTER:-${OPTIONS[0]}};
export ZONE=${ZONE:-${OPTIONS[1]}};
```

You can configure the scripts with custom cluster and zone with `-c YOUR_CLUSTER` and `-z YOUR_ZONE`. It will take the configuration from `kubectl config current-context` if you don't specify any.